# Thrift THttpTransport specification

Tags: thrift, thrift-protocol

I am looking for document that specifies how should THTTPTransport for Thrift be mapped on HTTP protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Its not brilliant but this is the best example I could find:

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/thrift/trunk/lib/csharp/src/Transport/THttpHandler.cs

Basically that's a IHttpHandler implementation in the current /trunk of Thrift (for c-sharp). Seems to do what you need?